# How to display the "animate property" diamond keyframe insert button (2.8x)

Tags: python, scripting, rigging, properties, panel

I am making a custom panel for a rig and I would like to be able to easily insert keyframes on my *rig properties* the same way we can already do in the default properties panel.

I'd basically like to add these buttons:

[image]

*As you can see, I already tried to implement them but I can't get them to work properly:*

[image]

**Q:** How to implement/draw these buttons for custom properties?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**`UILayout.use_property_split` and `UILayout.use_property_decorate`**

Setting [`UILayout.use_property_split`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.use_property_split)  in conjunction with  [`UILayout.use_property_decorate`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.use_property_decorate)  to `True`, marks down the animation button. (*Currently not over-documented*)  My understanding is the split makes room for it, and the decorate draws it.

[image]

With [developer extras](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/preferences/interface.html#prefs-interface-dev-extras) on, right click > view source. Found this in `bl_ui.properties_space.py` giving a big hint

```
    layout.use_property_decorate = False  # No animation.
```

Quick demo with object location, using the ***`Text Editor > Templates > Python > UI Simple Panel`*** template

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = True
        obj = context.object

        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(obj, "location")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Omg, Thank you, that worked brilliantly ! Just a little question, what is "developer extras" ? is it something we can enable in user preferences or something that is already in Blender (that I didn't know the name of) ?

Comment: @azagwen Yes, in setting panel, interface

Comment: Might be cool having a demo for multiple properties and how to set this up for only *one* of them.

Comment: @brockmann  Almost did... then didn't.  Surprised the answer hasn''t attracted much interest. Find it a handy little button.

Comment: Time will come, I think add-on dev's still busy replacing all the assignments with annotations :) No big deal, it's your answer @batFINGER