# Settings Button Keyframes on a Panel

Tags: python, scripting

Based on my earlier [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179404/add-a-keyframe-option-to-a-button-in-a-panel/179413?noredirect=1#comment300688_179413), I am trying to figure out how to keyframe a button in a panel. The button is not keyframing the location of the cube and it only changes the text on the button. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty

#win_man = bpy.types.WindowManager
bool_prop = bpy.props.BoolProperty

scene_man = bpy.types.Scene

def update_test(self, context):

    if not bpy.context.scene.test_toggle:
        bpy.data.objects["Cube"].location[0] = 1

    else:
        bpy.data.objects["Cube"].location[0] = 0

    return

#win_man.test = bool_prop(default = False, update = update_test)
scene_man.test_toggle = bool_prop(default = False, update = update_test)

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):

        #wm = context.window_manager
        sn = context.scene
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = True
        obj = context.object

        row = self.layout.row()
        sub = row.row()
        label = "cube = 0" if sn.test_toggle else "cube = 1"
        sub.prop(sn, 'test_toggle', text=label, toggle=True)

        return

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you expect this to work. As it is now the diamond (keyframe prop) adds a keyframe for the scene's  "test" property,  Changing the prop (pressing button)  fires an update that changes the location property of cube but doesn't add a keyframe for it.  You could add code to insert keyframe of cube in update method,.  Personally wouldn't go about it this way.  Would investigate driving the cube location x with `int(scene.test)`

Comment: Inserting a keyframe into the update_fuction worked but I want the location keyframe for the cube to be set when the keyframe prop is pressed. As you said, right now the keyframe prop sets a keyframe for the test property but not the location of the cube. If I add the keyframes in the update function, a keyframe will be added every time the button is pressed. My question is: How do I add the keyframe for the location of the cube (or a custom property) when the diamond keyframe property is pressed?

Comment: As mentioned in previous answer (a bit cryptically I suppose) showed the mark up for making a similar button to be an operator. This I believe is the go here. The keyframe diamond is designed to kf that prop, not others.  So.. either make an op that does this or look at keying sets (like LocRotScale) and make your own based on whatever.