# What does use_property_split and use_property_decorate do?

Tags: scripting

So I've been trying to figure out what use_property_split and use_property_decorate does. I've roughly figured out what it does but since there is no documentation on the official documentation I can only guess.
The official documentation is here the properties are undocumented:
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.use_property_split
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.use_property_decorate

So when I've tried using

```py
layout = self.layout
layout.use_property_split = True
```

In a panel it seems to affect only properties and properties that after the line layout.use_property_split and setting layout.use_property_split to true. **So what does layout.use_property_split = True do that I've seen?**

1. I think it ensures that the label of a property has enough space to be displayed in full if possible and then gives the rest of the space to the input box.
2. It will always cause the label of properties to be right aligned.
3. If the property is animateable e.g. EnumProperties, Float, Int it will add a animate circle to the right to allow the property to be animated.
4. For Float properties it will cause the label to be separated outside the input box instead of the usual label being inside the input box.

As for use_property_decorate again only affects lines after use_property_decorate = True and only for properties when I've tried using by itself like this, it doesn't do anything:

```py
layout = self.layout
layout.use_property_decorate = True
```

It doesn't even do anything like this:

```py
layout = self.layout
layout.use_property_split = True 
layout.use_property_decorate = True
```

The animate button appears the same as it did if you just had layout.use_property_split = True.

However, in this situation in here it does make a difference:

```py
layout = self.layout
layout.use_property_split = True 
layout.use_property_decorate = False
```

So from what I have observed, **what does layout.use_property_decorate do?**

1. So it must be used in combination with layout.use_property_split = True or else it won't have any effect.
2. It is in charge of whether the animate button appears to next to properties that might be able to be animated, when True the animate button will appear and when False the animate button will not appear. However, again it seems to default to True when layout.use_property_split = True .

So as a quick example of how to use it I've included the following simple example of use_property_split and use_property_decorate.

```py
import bpy

#define all user input properties
class PathProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    props_txt_path: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Select PropsTxt File*", description="Select a props.txt file", subtype="FILE_PATH")
    is_replace_nodes: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Replace Existing Shader Maps", default= True)
   

    texture_file_type_enum: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name = "Texture File Type",
        description = "Dropdown List of all the texture file types",
        items = 
        [
            (".tga" , ".tga", ""),
            (".png" , ".png", "")
        ]
        
    )
    principled_bsdf_emission_strength_float: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Principled BSDF Emission Strength if Emissions Texture Loaded", default = 5.0)


#code for drawing main panel in the 3D View
class LOADUESHADERSCRIPT_PT_main_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Load UE Shaders"
    bl_idname = "LOADUESHADERSCRIPT_PT_main_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "UE Shaders"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
        #store active/selected scene to variable
        scene = context.scene
        #allow access to user inputted properties through pointer
        #to properties
        pathtool = scene.path_tool
        
        #formatting
        #layout.use_property_split means that it will try and display 
        #the property fully
        layout.use_property_split = True

        #layout.use_property_decorate = True means that
        #the animation button will be shown
        #however, it defaults to True if
        #layout.use_property_split = True
        #so this line could be removed
        #for the same result
        layout.use_property_decorate = True
        
        #so just a reminder that use_property_split and
        #use property decorate only affect properties nothing else
        #so this label here would not be affected
        layout.label(text = "My panel")

        #so use_property_split will cause the label
        #here to be displayed fully if possible
        #but since it is not animateable the animate button 
        #will not appear
        layout.prop(pathtool, "props_txt_path")
        
        #so use_property_split will cause the label
        #here to be displayed fully if possible
        #since it is animateable the animate button 
        #will appear
        layout.prop(pathtool, "is_replace_nodes")

        #so use_property_split will cause the label
        #here to be displayed fully if possible
        #since it is animateable the animate button 
        #will appear
        layout.prop(pathtool, "texture_file_type_enum")

        #so use_property_split will cause the label
        #here to be displayed fully if possible outside the
        #input box instead of inside the input box
        #since it is animateable the animate button 
        #will appear
        layout.prop(pathtool, "principled_bsdf_emission_strength_float")
        
        #disable animate button appeaing from here on
        layout.use_property_decorate = False
        
        #so use_property_split will cause the label
        #here to be displayed fully if possible outside the
        #input box instead of inside the input box
        #it is animateable but the animate button will not appear
        #since layout.use_property_decorate = False
        layout.prop(pathtool, "principled_bsdf_emission_strength_float")


classes = [PathProperties, LOADUESHADERSCRIPT_PT_main_panel]
 
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
        
        #register path_tool as a type which has all
        #the user input properties from the properties class 
        bpy.types.Scene.path_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type = PathProperties)
 
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        
        #unregister path_tool as a type
        del bpy.types.Scene.path_tool
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161581/how-to-display-the-animate-property-diamond-keyframe-insert-button-2-8x